# ignoring row numbers of comment rows in python pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to read a CSV file into a pandas DataFrame, and I need to skip a certain row in the input file that comes after an unknown number of comment rows --- unknown in the sense that I'd like my code to work with multiple data files, and the number of these comment rows is not the same in all the files.   The CSV data files look like this:

```
#
# unknown
# number of comment
# rows
#
columnname1 columnname2 columnname3
line containing stuff I want to ignore (does NOT start with a comment char)
1.2 3.4 5.6
2.3 4.5 6.7
3.4 5.6 7.8
...
```

My first thought would be to do

```
pd.read_csv(filename, comment="#", skiprows=[1])
```

which says to skip the second row, but it turns out that `read_csv()` counts the comment lines when assigning row numbers, so the `skiprows=[1]` argument actually causes `read_csv()` to skip the second comment row in the file, rather than the second non-comment row.

I'm currently working around this with the function

```
def read_csv(file, *args, **kwargs):
    comment = kwargs["comment"] if "comment" in kwargs else False
    lines = "".join([line for line in open(file)
                     if not comment or not line.startswith(comment)])
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(lines), *args, **kwargs)
```

which works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way, such as a combination of options to `read_csv()` that will cause it to not count comment lines when figuring row numbers, and/or a way to filter the data that `read_csv()` sees that does not involve loading the entire file into memory at one.

Suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Unless your data is not exactly as shown in your question. Why not drop non integer/float values?

Comment: The line containing stuff I want to ignore contains values that are strings, not numbers, so if I let read_csv() treat it as a row of data, it messes with the column datatypes that read_csv() infers. I know I could pass explicit column types to read_csv(), but I'm also interested in being able to handle other situations where the input data contains certain rows that I want to ignore, but not at predictable line numbers.